# javascript collection for year and month

Tags: javascript, collections

Noob here :)

I have a list of item which have a date. 
I would like the user to be able to choose (using drop down lists) to display all item in a given month within in a given year, however not all month have items and i would like the user to see only relevant months\years, so the user will first choose a year and then the month dropdown will be populated based on relevant months.

for that i think it would be useful to create a data structure which is built from the list of item dates, that is like a 2d array but with a year index and each element holds an array of the months that actually have items in them.

Is there any simple way of doing this in Javascript or do i need to write custom code for that?

Thanks.

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding the question. What makes a month relevant to years?

Comment: Can you add a sample of the data? Mostly to show how the month and year are stored in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [**underscore.js**](http://underscorejs.org/) library and its [groupBy](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) function.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uL3xvwf9/):

```
var result = _.groupBy(data, 'year');

_.each(result, function(element, year) {
    result[year] = _.groupBy(element, 'month');
});
```